# Javascript matchmedia dont work on Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

this script work on chrome, mozilla but dont work on safari, It choose which is downstairs and load function

what is mistake? can anyone help me? im tired..

```
  if (window.matchMedia('(min-width:701px)').matches) {
   function toggleNav() {
    if(mySidenav.style.width === "225px"){
        document.getElementById("responsive").style.width = "45px";
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "45px";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "45px";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("responsive").style.width = "225px";
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").setAttribute( 'style', 'width:225px !important' );
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "225px";
    }

   }
}    

if (window.matchMedia('(max-width:700px)').matches) {
console.log('match');
 function toggleNav() {
    if(document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width === "100%"){
        document.getElementById("responsive").style.width = "0px";
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0px";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0px";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("responsive").style.width = "100%";
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").setAttribute( 'style', 'width:100% !important' );
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "100%";
    }

    }
  }
```

Comment: no one know why? :(

Comment: :(((((((((((((((

Comment: What version of Safari? If it's the one on Windows then it's normal and just drop it since it is of no use (it has nothing to do with what the current version is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will detect it, with new function for safari

```
   var sidenava = document.getElementsByClassName('sidenava');
  var is_safari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
if(is_safari){
var w,b;
w = window.outerWidth;
if(w > 700){
    b = '225px';
}else{
    b = '0';
}
function toggleNav() {
    if(mySidenav.style.width === b){
        document.getElementById("responsive").style.width = "0px";
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").setAttribute('style', 'width:0px !important');
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0px";
        document.getElementById("mainContent").style.marginLeft = "0px";
        document.getElementById("footer_wrapper").style.marginLeft = "0px";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("responsive").style.width = "225px";
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").setAttribute('style', 'width:225px !important');
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "225px";
        document.getElementById("mainContent").style.marginLeft = "225px";
        document.getElementById("footer_wrapper").style.marginLeft = "225px";
        document.getElementById("dashboard").onclick = function() {closed()};
        document.getElementById("form").onclick = function() {closed()};
        function closed(){
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").setAttribute('style', 'width:0px !important');
            document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0px";
            document.getElementById("mainContent").style.marginLeft = "0px";
            document.getElementById("footer_wrapper").style.marginLeft = "0px";
            document.getElementById("responsive").style.width = "0px";
           }
       }

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

for anyone else having similar problems, I've found in my case that safari needs the 'screen' specification as well ast the width. Other browsers seem to assume you mean screen width but safri didn't in my case, so it would be:

if ( window.matchMedia('screen and (min-width:701px)').matches) {}

may not be the solution in all cases but worked for me